# Horizontal scroll in appium

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

How can i horizontally scroll in the appium
like for Vertical scroll we do
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("")");

is there like that???

Answer (score 1):

You can set the UiSelector to scrollable and set direction of scrolling

```
driver().findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)."
                + "resourceId(\"<id of scrollable control>\"))"
                + ".setAsHorizontalList().scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"<text to search for>\"))");
```

Link gives details about [UiScrollable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html)

Comment: This is helped me to find out elements in a horizontal scroll view. but it clicks on another element when I use click().

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this way this will work horizontal and also by changing  scroll start and scroll end you can use same code for  vertical scroll also.

```
public void scrollHorizontal(double value1,double value2) {

Dimension dimension =driver.manage().window().getSize();
Double scrollheight = dimension.getHeight()*value1;
int scrollStart = scrollheight.intValue();

Double scrollheightEnd = dimension.getHeight()*value2;

int scrollEnd = scrollheightEnd.intValue();

new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions)driver)
.press(PointOption.point(scrollStart,0))
.waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
.moveTo(PointOption.point(scrollEnd , 0))
.release()
.perform(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below method for horizontally scrolling:

```
public static void swipeHorizontal(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
        int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
        int endPoint = (int) (size.width * finalPercentage);
        new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(endPoint, anchor).release().perform();
    }
```

Call above method by:

```
swipeHorizontal((AppiumDriver) driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This applies in all directions:

enum:

```
public enum DIRECTION {
    DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

actual code:

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction) {
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

        case UP:
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

    }
}
```

usage:

```
swipe(driver, Util.DIRECTION.RIGHT);
```

Hope this helps,